# Swift 3 NSAttributedString multiple attributes

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

just started swift 3 and I have problems with swift syntax.

i'm trying to display a simple `NSAttributedString`.

so 1st I set my attributes :

```
let attributeFontSaySomething : [String : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.fontSaySomething()]
let attributeColorSaySomething : [String : AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blue]
```

Then I create my string :

```
let attStringSaySomething = NSAttributedString(string: "Say something", attributes: self.attributeFontSaySomething)
```

What i would like to do is to create the string with my 2 attributes not only just one. But when i do :

```
let attStringSaySomething = NSAttributedString(string: "Say something", attributes: [self.attributeFontSaySomething, self.attributeColorSaySomething])
```

Xcode tells me I can't and want me to change this for a literal dictionary.

How can I create my string with the 2 attributes without using a `NSMutableAttributedString` ?

Comment: does the attributes have to be wrapped into variables?

Comment: No no, just to more clear.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The main issue is that you are passing an **array** `[attr.. , attr...]` rather than one **dictionary**.

You need to merge the two dictionaries into one

```
let attributeFontSaySomething : [String : Any] = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)]
let attributeColorSaySomething : [String : Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blue]

var attributes = attributeFontSaySomething
for (key, value) in attributeColorSaySomething {
    attributes(value, forKey: key)
}

let attStringSaySomething = NSAttributedString(string: "Say something", attributes: attributes)
```

However it might be easier to create the dictionary literally:

```
let attributes : [String : Any] = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blue]
```

Answer (score 7):

Just create a single dictionary with both sets of attributes:

```
let attributes: [String:AnyObject] = 
  [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.fontSaySomething(), 
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blue]
```

And then use the dictionary with both key/value pairs when creating your attributed string.

There's no built-in mechanism in Swift for combining dictionaries, but you could add an override of the `+` operator if you wanted to be able to add dictionaries together (You'd have to work out what to do if both dictionaries contained the same key however.)

Comment: Could I ask to check for Swift 4.0 version? I first tried to make [NSAttributedStringKey: AnyObject] array, but I cannot use any NSAttribute...Name.

Answer (score 3):

**Thanks for @vadian's answer**

**Update For Swift 4**

```
let attributes : [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue) : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0), NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue) : UIColor(hex:"4C0000")]

refreshControl.attributedTitle=NSAttributedString(string: "Refreshing...", attributes: attributes)
```

Comment: You are taking an `NSAttributedStringKey`, converting it into a `String`, and then using that `String` to construct an `NSAttributedStringKey`. There is no need for that at all. Just use the `NSAttributedStringKey`. In fact, you can just use `.font` instead of `NSAttributedStringKey.font`.

Answer (score 2):

Use like this:

```
let attStringSaySomething = NSAttributedString.init(string: "Hello", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.black])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for different attributes on different strings With Roboto font (For **Roboto font** use `MDFRobotoFontLoader`)

```
let yourAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black, NSFontAttributeName: MDFRobotoFontLoader.sharedInstance().regularFont(ofSize: 20)]

let finalString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "", attributes: yourAttributes)

let attributeStr =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "XYZGFDGii", attributes: yourAttributes)
       finalString.append(attributeStr)

let yourOtherAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red, NSFontAttributeName: MDFRobotoFontLoader.sharedInstance().regularFont(ofSize: 24)]

let partTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "hfjghlkdhkjld", attributes: yourOtherAttributes)
       finalString.append(partTwo)
```

This example uses Roboto font

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are inserting two dictionaries into a dictionary, what only expects `[String: Any]`, not `[[String: Any], [String: Any]]` type.
You can do the following:

```
let attStringSaySomething = NSAttributedString(string: "Say something", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.fontSaySomething(), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blue])
```

You could also group the values into tuples instead of dictionaries, and insert them into your dictionary based on the key and value:

```
let attributeFontSaySomething = (key: NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.fontSaySomething())
let attributeColorSaySomething = (key: NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blue)

let attStringSaySomething = NSAttributedString(string: "Say something", attributes: [attributeFontSaySomething.key : attributeFontSaySomething.value,attributeColorSaySomething.key : attributeColorSaySomething.value])
```

Comment: Oh it crashes using AsyncDisplayKit

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers are out dated here, especially for Swift 4 and above, you can use something like:

```
let wholeString = "This is whole string"
let partToAttribute = "whole string"

let attributedMessage = NSMutableAttributedString(string: wholeString)
    .highlightString(with: UIColor.blue, for: partToAttribute, isBackground: true)
    .fontHighlightString(with: UIFont.makeBoldFont(size: 16), color: UIColor.white, for: partToAttribute)

titleLabel.attributedText = attributedMessage
```

So at the end, you apply 2 attributes which are `highlightString` and `fontHighlightString`

Answer (score 0):

First you can initialise attributes by using

```
var myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.init(hexString: "#FFAEA9"), NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Dubai-Medium", size: 16) ]
```

after that you can use it...

```
  let myString = "Enter default amount"
            let text = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttribute)
            enterCustomAmount.setAttributedTitle(text, for: .normal)
```